# Is there a way to suppress the waving pendulum animation in Firefox tab titles during load?

Tags: firefox, wait, ux, indicator

Is there a way to suppress the waving pendulum animation in Firefox tab titles during load? I'm seeing this in my latest update (57.0.1). Pretty sure it wasn't there before as it's driving me crazy.

Some kind of busy indicator is obviously helpful (the good ol' whirly wheel is fine) but I find this tick-tock movement very distracting and annoying. I would prefer to change the busy indicator (or have no busy indicator at all, if that's the only way to get rid of this thing).

I've searched in about:config for things like "tab" and "anim" but come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to suppress the waving pendulum animation in Firefox tab titles?

Yes. You can choose from several different animations.

You need to install ['Classic' css tweaks for Firefox 57+](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/issues/2).

Complete install instructions can be found on the [main page](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx).

I installed ['Classic' CSS tweaks for Firefox 57+ v1.4.5](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/releases).

There is a section of css in the supplied `userChrome.css` that can change the tab load animation:

```
/* custom tab loading animation - only use one at a time ****************************************/
/* @import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_blue_fx56.css); /**/
@import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_blue.css);
/* @import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_grey_classic.css); /**/
/* @import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_green.css); /**/
/* @import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_orange_ubuntu.css); /**/
```

I chose to uncomment the `@import url(./css/tabs/tab_throbber_blue.css);` line which gives a "blue whirly wheel".

There is a nice overview of the project at [Customize Firefox 57 with CSS](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/11/13/customize-firefox-57-with-css/).